# update entered details on specific id in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the entered details in editentries.php. But when I enter details and click on Update it is not updating in database. I am using REPLACE query to do it. Help me out what should I do?

This is editentries.php

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']) && isset($_POST['editid'])){
  $id = $_POST['editid'];
  $selectname=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY name");
  $selectaddress=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY address");
  $selectemail=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY email");
  $selectphoneno=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY phoneno");
  $selectprice=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM feedetails where id = $id GROUP BY price");





?>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10"><br><br><br>
  <h2>Update Applicant Details</h2><hr>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<form method="post" action="entries.php">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Applicant ID:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

      <?php  
        echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="id" readonly value="'.$id.'">';

       ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectname)){
        echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="name" value="'.$res['name'].'">';
      }
       ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectaddress)){
        echo '<textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="address">'.$res['address'].'</textarea>';
      }
       ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone no.:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectphoneno)){
        echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="phoneno" value="'.$res['phoneno'].'">';
      }
       ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email ID:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <?php  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($selectemail)){
        echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="email" value="'.$res['email'].'">';
      }
       ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="Update">
    </div>
  </div>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["address"]) && isset($_POST["phoneno"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST['update']))
{
  $sid= $_POST["id"]; 
$name= $_POST["name"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$phoneno= $_POST["phoneno"];
$email= $_POST["email"];

$update="REPLACE INTO feedetails(id,subjects,price,name,address,email,phoneno) VALUES ('$sid','$name','$address','$email','$phoneno')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$update))
{
echo " <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript'>
    window.alert('Record updated');
    window.location.href='entries.php';
    </SCRIPT>";
}
else
{
  mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
} ?>
```

I want to update details in database on that specific id but it is not working at all

Comment: "_it is not working at all_" Is not the most detailed error description. In your `REPLACE INTO` you have 7 fields to be updated but only 5 values

Comment: @kerbholz but we need to specify all the column names of table

Comment: If you have 7 columns to be changed I guess you'd also need 7 fields for the columns to be filled with.  You `subjects` column would get replaced with the value of `$email`, is that what you want? I guess not. You should probably use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), not `replace`

Comment: i used update query its not working.

Answer (score 0):

rather than submiting the delete to return a javascript use Ajax & Jquery
add id to your submit button i.e id="delsub"

```
$("#delsub").click(function(){
var id = $("#id").val();
dataString = "delete=" + id;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "deleteentry.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
    alert('Record deleted');
    window.location.href='entries.php';
}
});
});
```

In your deleteentry.php change $_REQUEST to $_POST

Answer (score -1):

"UPDATE your_table SET name='$name',address='$address',email='$email',phoneno='$phoneno' WHERE id='$sid'"

Answer (score -1):

```
$query=" UPDATE /*table-name */ SET  name='$_POST[name]' WHERE id= ' ".$id." ' " ;
```

Example:-

```
$query=" UPDATE register SET  name='$_POST[name]' WHERE id= ' ".$id." ' " ;
```

Comment: PHP will default to treating your array keys as constants, then fall back to parsing as a string while throwing an E_NOTICE.

Answer (score -2):

The Replace function in SQL is used to update the content of a string ,it is not used to update data.

You can use SQL UPDATE Statement.

So your sql query is like this,

> $update="UPDATE feedetails SET name = '".$name."', address=
>   '".$address."', email="'.$email.'", phoneno="'.$phoneno.'" WHERE id
>   =".$id;